# AngularJs - `$http` works But `$resource` not working - how to apply `$http` params to `$resource`

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http

I am trying to post the image informations to back-end. I tried with `$resource` but not working. But when i tried with `$http` it seems that works. But i have added some of additiona params to `$http` - but i don't know how i can apply those `params` to `$resource` any one help me please?

```
$scope.photoData = function (photoData) {

         console.log( "photo data", photoData ); //consoles properly

        var fileData = photoData[0];
        var data = new FormData();

         var fileASHXPath =   _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/UploadImage/';

         //this is not working!
         $resource(fileASHXPath).save({ "photoData" : fileData }).$promise.then( function ( response ) {

            console.log( response ); //nothing works!

         })

        //this is works!

         var base = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/UploadImage/';

         $http({
             url: base + 'TestImage.jpg',
             method: 'POST',
             processData: false,
             headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
             data: fileData
         }
                 )
                 .success(function (data) {

                     if (data.Message.toLowerCase() == 'success') {

                         console.log(data);
                     }                    

                 })
                 .error(function (msg, code) {

                     console.log('error method called');

                 });

     }
```

**UPDATE - My NEW TRY**

**Still not working**

```
$resource(base + fileName, {}, {

            post:{
                method:"POST",
                isArray:false,
                headers:{'Content-Type':'undefined'}
            }

        }).$promise.then(function ( response ) {

            console.log( "response is", response );

        })
```

Comment: you might have forgot to declare it as a parameter for controller function.

Comment: I am not getting you.. please help me further, If possible post me your suggesion

Comment: As far I know, we will get `$scope`, `$http` and others by declaring as a parameters right? In my application I was getting `$window` as undefined because I wasn't using that parameter in controller declared function. (`app.controller("ctrlLogin", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window) {});`). So I think you may have forgot to declare as a parameter.

Comment: No, I have declared those. generally in case if I am not declare, I will get error. In my case I din't get any error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. That is after $resource definition, call post() with form data.

```
$scope.photoData = function (photoData) {

  console.log( "photo data", photoData ); //consoles properly

  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("photoData", photoData[0]);

  var fileASHXPath =   _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/UploadImage/';

  $resource(fileASHXPath, {}, {
      post: {
        method: 'POST',
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
      }
    }
    ).post({}, fd).$promise.then(function ( response ) {

      console.log( "response is", response );

  });
});
```

Comment: from `fd` how can i get the 'image name` ? ( usually i do `photoData[0].name`

Comment: You can't get image name because FormData doesn't provide it. It is just an object. You can get name from any backend language like PHP etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the resource. That is after `$resource` definition, call `post()`.

```
    $resource(base + fileName, {}, {

        post:{
            method:"POST",
            isArray:false,
            headers:{'Content-Type':'undefined'}
        }

    }).post().$promise.then(function ( response ) {

        console.log( "response is", response );

    })
```